# Selenium element was not scrolled into the viewport when the element is "huge"

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm doing a unit test with Selenium Webdriver with Python. When I tried to test clicking an element on a webpage, there is an error:
IE: 11, Windows-7

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: The point at which the driver is attempting to click on the element was not scrolled into the viewport.
```

even if I tried to move the element vertically and horizontally in the view. There is still and error when I click on the element with `e.click()`.
I searched online and found this, and changed `e.click()` to `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click(e).perform()`. Now it goes through, but it doesn't actually click, it seems it just skip this line.

Here is my code snippet:

```
e = elems.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='schedItem_10262']/div[2]") # find the sub-element from elems by xpath
self.scroll_element_into_view(e)
e.click()
#webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(e).click(e).perform()

def scroll_element_into_view(self, element):
    """Scroll element into view"""
    x = element.location['x']
    self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({0}, 0)'.format(x))
    y = element.location['y']
    self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, {0})'.format(y))
```

The problem happens when the element is "huge" that it can't fit into the window. Is there any way I can click on a "huge" element?

I'm very new to this. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

**Update:**
Access and click with the following code:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='schedItem_10262']/div[2]")
self.scroll_element_into_view(e)
e.click()
```

[image: pic]

Here is a snapshot, It's timeline showing all the cases, There are two cases in this picture. "Hernia" and "Trans". The red one "Hernia" lasts very long, so it's not fully displayed on the webpage.

I wanna click on every case one by one to see if there is windows pops-up for each case. When I try to click manully both cases, they work fine. But when I tried to click with `click()`  "Hernia" will cause the error, `element was not scrolled into the viewport`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scrollTo()`, call [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the desired element:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I tried your solution, but got the same error:(   It works perfectly fine on a relatively small element. Is it because selenium can't handle "large" element click? I'm sure part of the large element is visible and when I try to click on it manually, it works fine.

Comment: @Julia hm, thanks for the quick turnaround! Can you share a reproduceable example? (would be easier to help)

Comment: Sorry, I can share the code, but the server is not public to test on. I updated my post. Please check if it helps. Thank you~~